# Fastest way to apply histcount on an array grouped by previous bin result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have 2 large numpy arrays which I need to bin according to some bin values. The first array needs to be binned with the data1Bins values. Then the data in the second array needs to be grouped by the result of the bins on the first array. When this grouping is done, the amount of values in each bin needs to be counted.

This counted result needs to be added as a row to a data frame and in the end the total sum of the data frames needs to be calculated so each element can be divided by the total sum value.

Despite my working solution, I'm wondering if there isn't a more elegant or faster solution. Time is a very important thing since this function will be executed many times.

So that all said I'm always happy hear possible improvements regarding this small piece of code. The current timing is `0.009527206420898438 s`.

**Current solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

data1 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=25, size=(50,))
data2 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=25, size=(50,))

data1Bins = [0, *np.arange(1.5, 25, 1), 100]
data2Bins = [0, *np.arange(7.5, 360, 15), 360]

# Speed up from here ->
start = time.time()
inds = np.digitize(data1, data1Bins)

df = pd.DataFrame()

# 25 bins
for i in range(0, len(data1Bins)):
    binned_data = data2[np.asarray(inds == i).nonzero()[0].tolist()]
    count, bin_edges = np.histogram(binned_data, bins=data2Bins)
    count = np.array([(count[0] + count[-1]), *count[1:-1]])

    df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(count.reshape(-1, len(count)))])


# Set index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Get total sum
total_sum = df.sum().sum()

# Devide each element by total sum
df = df/ total_sum

df['Name'] = 'abc'
df['Id'] = 'def'
df['Nr'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])

print(time.time() - start)

print(df)
```

**End result:**

```
        0         1         2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24 Name   Id  Nr
0   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   0
1   0.020408  0.020408  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   1
2   0.020408  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   2
3   0.020408  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   3
4   0.000000  0.020408  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   4
5   0.000000  0.020408  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   5
6   0.061224  0.040816  0.020408  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   6
7   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   7
8   0.020408  0.081633  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   8
9   0.000000  0.040816  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def   9
10  0.081633  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  10      
11  0.000000  0.040816  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  11      
12  0.000000  0.020408  0.020408  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  12      
13  0.000000  0.040816  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  13      
14  0.000000  0.040816  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  14      
15  0.000000  0.020408  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  15      
16  0.000000  0.000000  0.020408  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  16      
17  0.000000  0.020408  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  17      
18  0.020408  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  18      
19  0.040816  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  19
20  0.000000  0.020408  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  20
21  0.020408  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  21
22  0.020408  0.040816  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  22
23  0.020408  0.020408  0.020408  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  23
24  0.000000  0.081633  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  abc  def  24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is the baseline timing I have on my machine when executing the code after the `# Speed up from here` comment :

```
5.02 ms ± 134 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

You will save time by appending values to a list and then creating a dataframe, rather than using `pd.concat()`.

```py
# [...]

data = []

for i in range(0, len(data1Bins)):
    binned_data = data2[np.asarray(inds == i).nonzero()[0].tolist()]
    count, bin_edges = np.histogram(binned_data, bins=data2Bins)
    count = np.array([(count[0] + count[-1]), *count[1:-1]])
    data.append(count)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# [...]
```

```
1.97 ms ± 36.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Here are also a few improvements that will save non-significant time, but will make your code cleaner

```py
for i in range(0, len(data1Bins)):
    # cleaner way to get binned_data
    binned_data = data2[np.where(inds == i)]  
    count, bin_edges = np.histogram(binned_data, bins=data2Bins)
    
    # cleaner way to get the values added to the dataframe
    values = np.concatenate(([count[0] + count[-1]], count[1:-1]))
    data.append(values)
```

```
1.93 ms ± 45.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```